# assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast enabled by default

Tags: c, unix, pointers, design-patterns, operating-system

When I compile this code:

```
void rep_and_print(char * str, char * patt, int l, int i)
{
    char * pch; // pointer to occurence
    char * s;
    s = str; // save original pointer
    if (i == 0)
    {
        while ( (pch = strstr(str,patt)) != NULL)
        {
            // FOUND
            memset (pch,'*',l); // Set asterisk
            str = pch + l; // move pointer to the end of asterisks to found new  occurences
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while ( (pch = strcasestr(str,patt)) != NULL)
        {
            // FOUND
            memset (pch,'*',l); // Set asterisk
            str = pch + l; // move pointer to the end of asterisks to found new occurences
        }
    }
    printf ("%s",s);
}
```

I got this error:

> warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
>   [enabled by default]

```
while ( (pch = strcasestr(str,patt)) != NULL)
```

and there is an arrow point to the equal sign that is between `pch` and `strcasestr`

Comment: Do you also get warnings when you compile with `-Wall`? `strcasestr` isn't a standard function and may not be defined in `<string.h>`, so that your compiler assumes that it returns an `int`. That would explain why ther isn't an error for the same code with `strstr`.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page:

> ```
>    #define _GNU_SOURCE
>
>    #include <string.h>
>
>    char *strcasestr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
> ```

You need to add `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before you `#include <string.h>` (and `#include <stdio.h>` as well) in order for the function declaration to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

while ( (pch = strcasestr(str,patt)) != NULL) 
strcasestr is a nonstandard extension, so you must add #define _GNU_SOURCE on the first line of your file, or compile with -D_GNU_SOURCE.